# Prevent FORTRAN from closing when a character is inputed instead of a number

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a read statement that expects a number, very simple example code:

```
program test
integer var
read(*,*) var
end
```

The thing is that I usually input a string of characters (ie: *yes*) on account of being distracted. How can I prevent my code from halting entirely and instead display an error message of the type *You've entered an incorrect value. Try again*?

I'm thinking something like:

```
    program test
    integer var
10  read(*,*) var
    if (var.not.a.number) then
      write(*,*)'You've entered an incorrect value. Try again'
      goto 10
    endif
    end
```

What would that **var.not.a.number** condition look like?
I use `gfortran` to compile under Ubuntu.

---

**Edit**: Thank you all! I ended up implementing HPM's 3rd option since it was the simplest one:

```
    program test
    integer var,iostat,ios
10  read(*,*,iostat=ios) var
    if (ios.ne.0) then
      write(*,*)'You've entered an incorrect value. Try again'
      goto 10
    endif
    end
```

Special thanks to `User7391` who took the effort to write all that code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using *list-directed input*.  The second `*` in the statement `read(*,*)` essentially tells the compiler/run-time system that you will provide it with something at run time that can be interpreted as an `integer`.  If you want to give yourself the freedom to make mistakes on input you have (at least) 3 choices.

1. You can, as @User7391's answer already says, read the input into a character variable and parse it yourself.  That kind user has even offered to write the code for you !
2. You could modify the read command to something like `read(*,*,err=1234)` where `1234` is the label of your error-handling statement(s). This approach is now considered rather old-fashioned and might be frowned upon.
3. You could modify the read command to something like `read(*,*,iostat=ios)` where `ios` is an integer variable which catches the `iostat` (i/o status flag) reported by the `read` statement.  You might then write the line `if (iostat/=0) ...` for error handling.  This is considered to be the more up to date approach.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could read in the value into a character variable and then process that character variable accordingly.

If it contains only numbers, store it in var, else, report an error and loop back around.

To check if a character is only numeric, consider this example code:

```
PROGRAM test
CHARACTER(len=100) :: input
LOGICAL :: is_numeric, success
INTEGER :: var

DO 
READ(*,*) :: input
IF (is_numeric(input)) THEN
  READ(input,*) var
  success = .TRUE.
ELSE
  WRITE(*,*) 'ERROR: Input is not numeric.'
END IF

IF (success) THEN
  break
END IF

END DO

END PROGRAM test


LOGICAL FUNCTION is_numeric(string)
  IMPLICIT NONE
  CHARACTER(len=*), INTENT(IN) :: string
  LOGICAL :: is_numeric
  INTEGER :: var
  INTEGER :: error_val
  READ(string,*,IOSTAT=error_val) x ! This line converts string to an integer
                            ! If there was an error, the error_val variable is
                            ! non-zero

  is_numeric = error_val==0

END FUNCTION is_numeric
```

Tell me if you need help with writing the example code.

You'd need to be able to convert a character to an integer. This is possible with internal read/write statements.

Comment: Note with this apporach you can further handle input strings, eg allow "end" to end entry for example.

Answer (score 3):

Using old FORTRAN:

```
90 continue
read (*, *, err=90) number
```

This can be made more elaborate, where you test for the error and output an error message.